# Problems with Code Igniter manual instalation

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-4

Codeigniter 4 shows this error: **SYSTEMPATH\CodeIgniter.php at line 224**. (the full error body, below)

Looks like missing **$extension intl** is the problem. I allready edit the php.ini file,
removing the semicolons from **;extension=intl**.

Still doesn't work. Any idea how to fix this?

```
217             {
218                 $missingExtensions[] = $extension;
219             }
220         }
221 
222         if ($missingExtensions)
223         {
224             throw FrameworkException::forMissingExtension(implode(', ', $missingExtensions));
225         }
226     }
227 
228     //--------------------------------------------------------------------
229 
230     /**
231      * Initializes Kint
```

Backtrace Server Request Response Files Memory
SYSTEMPATH\CodeIgniter.php : 224   —  CodeIgniter\Exceptions\FrameworkException::forMissingExtension ( arguments )

$extension  intl

```
217             {
218                 $missingExtensions[] = $extension;
219             }
220         }
221 
222         if ($missingExtensions)
223         {
224             throw FrameworkException::forMissingExtension(implode(', ', $missingExtensions));
225         }
226     }
227 
228     //--------------------------------------------------------------------
229 
230     /**
231      * Initializes Kint
```

SYSTEMPATH\CodeIgniter.php : 172   —  CodeIgniter\CodeIgniter->resolvePlatformExtensions ()

```
165         // Setup Exception Handling
166         Services::exceptions()->initialize();
167 
168         // Run this check for manual installations
169         if (! is_file(COMPOSER_PATH))
170         {
171             // @codeCoverageIgnoreStart
172             $this->resolvePlatformExtensions();
173             // @codeCoverageIgnoreEnd
174         }
175 
176         // Set default locale on the server
177         locale_set_default($this->config->defaultLocale ?? 'en');
178 
179         // Set default timezone on the server
```

SYSTEMPATH\bootstrap.php : 159   —  CodeIgniter\CodeIgniter->initialize ()

```
152  *
153  * The CodeIgniter class contains the core functionality to make
154  * the application run, and does all of the dirty work to get
155  * the pieces all working together.
156  */
157 
158 $app = new CodeIgniter(new App());
159 $app->initialize();
160 
161 return $app;
162 
require FCPATH\index.php   —   require()
```

Comment: Did you edit the correct `php.ini` file? Use `phpinfo()` in a `.php` file to show if the extension has been loaded and which `php.ini` to edit. Restart your webserver after making changes

Comment: You are right, I'm using the WAMP (not MAMP) php.ini file -> but the row "extension=intl" doesn't have semicolons in WAMP's php.ini file either.

Comment: There are two versions of PHP.ini file. One for CLI and another for Web. Make sure you are changing for the Web and Not CLI. Another potential issue might be you don't have that particular module installed.

Comment: Please share more details, like the error message itself

Answer (score -3):

Go to your php.ini file and uncomment the extension=intl

Comment: Please share more details such that others can learn from your answer. According to the question, the OP already tried that without success